# OpenGL Shadow Mapping using GLSL

Tags: python, opengl, glsl, shader, pyopengl

I am trying to get shadow mapping working using GLSL. Unfortunately my depth render results are unusable even I have a pretty decent depth buffer precision. It is rendering like wireframe, following image may be a better description.

I am also including a test case(single file including shader), only dependency is pyopengl.

[image]

```
# shadow mapping test
# utkualtinkaya at gmail 
# shader is from http://www.fabiensanglard.net/shadowmapping/index.php

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import * 
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GL.shaders import *
from OpenGL.GL.framebufferobjects import *
import math

class Camera:
    def __init__(self):
        self.rotx, self.roty = math.pi/4, math.pi/4
        self.distance = 100
        self.moving = False
        self.ex, self.ey = 0, 0
        self.size = (800, 600) 

    def load_matrices(self):
        glViewport(0, 0, *self.size)
        y = math.cos(self.roty) * self.distance
        x = math.sin(self.roty) * math.cos(self.rotx) * self.distance
        z = math.sin(self.roty) * math.sin(self.rotx) * self.distance

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(45.0, self.size[0]/float(self.size[1]), 1, 1000)

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(x,y,z, 0,0,0, 0,1,0)

    def on_mouse_button (self, b, s, x, y):
        self.moving = not s
        self.ex, self.ey = x, y
        if b in [3, 4]:
            dz = (1 if b == 3 else -1)
            self.distance += self.distance/15.0 * dz;

    def on_mouse_move(self, x, y, z = 0):
        if self.moving:            
            self.rotx += (x-self.ex) / 300.0
            self.roty += -(y-self.ey) / 300.0
            self.ex, self.ey = x, y

    def set_size(self, w, h):
        self.size = w, h

class Shader():
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_built = False
        self.uniforms = {}

    def build(self):
        self.program = compileProgram(
        compileShader('''
            uniform mat4 camMatrix;
            uniform mat4 shadowMatrix;
            varying vec4 depthProjection;
            uniform bool useShadow;

            void main() {
                gl_Position = camMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
                depthProjection = shadowMatrix * gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
                gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
            }
        ''',GL_VERTEX_SHADER),
        compileShader('''
            varying vec4 depthProjection;
            uniform sampler2D shadowMap;
            uniform bool useShadow;

            void main () {
                float shadow = 1.0;
                if (useShadow) {
                    vec4 shadowCoord = depthProjection / depthProjection.w ;
                    // shadowCoord.z -= 0.0003;            
                    float distanceFromLight = texture2D(shadowMap, shadowCoord.st).z;                                
                    if (depthProjection .w > 0.0)
                        shadow = distanceFromLight < shadowCoord.z ? 0.5 : 1.0 ;            

                    }
                gl_FragColor = shadow * gl_Color;
              }
        ''',GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER),)
        self.is_built = True

        self.uniforms['camMatrix'] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'camMatrix')
        self.uniforms['shadowMatrix'] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'shadowMatrix')
        self.uniforms['shadowMap'] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'shadowMap')
        self.uniforms['useShadow'] = glGetUniformLocation(self.program, 'useShadow')
        print self.uniforms

    def use(self):
        if not self.is_built:
            self.build()
        glUseProgram(self.program)

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        glutInit(sys.argv)
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
        glutInitWindowSize(800, 600)
        glutInitWindowPosition(1120/2, 100)
        self.window = glutCreateWindow("Shadow Test")
        self.cam = Camera()
        self.light = Camera()
        self.cam.set_size(800, 600)
        self.light.set_size(2048, 2048)
        self.light.distance = 100
        self.shader = Shader()
        self.initialized = False        

    def setup(self):
        self.initialized = True
        glClearColor(0,0,0,1.0);
        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        self.fbo = glGenFramebuffers(1);
        self.shadowTexture = glGenTextures(1)

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fbo)

        w, h = self.light.size

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5)         
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.shadowTexture)

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
        glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );

        glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, w, h, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)

        glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)
        glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)

        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.fbo, 0)

        FBOstatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER)
        if FBOstatus != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
            print ("GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_EXT failed, CANNOT use FBO\n");

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)
        #glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0)                

    def draw(self):
        glPushMatrix()
        glTranslate(0, 10 ,0)
        glColor4f(0, 1, 1, 1)
        glutSolidCube(5)
        glPopMatrix()

        glPushMatrix()
        glColor4f(0.5, 0.5, .5, 1)
        glScale(100, 1, 100)
        glutSolidCube(1)
        glPopMatrix()

    def apply_camera(self, cam):
        cam.load_matrices()
        model_view = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
        projection = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glMultMatrixd(projection)
        glMultMatrixd(model_view)        
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.shader.uniforms['camMatrix'], 1, False, glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX))
        glLoadIdentity()     

    def shadow_pass(self):
        glUniform1i(self.shader.uniforms['useShadow'], 0)

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, self.fbo)
        glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glCullFace(GL_FRONT)
        self.apply_camera(self.light)        
        self.draw()
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0)

    def final_pass(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        self.light.load_matrices()
        model_view = glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX);
        projection = glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX);        
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        bias = [ 0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 
                 0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0,
                 0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0,
                 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0]
        glLoadMatrixd(bias)
        glMultMatrixd(projection)
        glMultMatrixd(model_view)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(self.shader.uniforms['shadowMatrix'], 1, False, glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX))

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE5)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.shadowTexture)                
        glUniform1i(self.shader.uniforms['shadowMap'], 5)

        glUniform1i(self.shader.uniforms['useShadow'], 1);

        self.apply_camera(self.cam)
        glLoadIdentity()
        glCullFace(GL_BACK)
        self.draw()

    def render(self):
        if not self.initialized: self.setup()
        self.shader.use()        
        self.shadow_pass()
        self.final_pass()        
        glutSwapBuffers()

    def mouse_move(self, *args):
        self.cam.on_mouse_move(*args)
        self.light.on_mouse_move(*args)

    def mouse_button(self, b, *args):
        if b==0:
            self.light.on_mouse_button(b, *args)
        else:
            self.cam.on_mouse_button(b, *args)

    def main(self):
        glutDisplayFunc(self.render)
        glutIdleFunc(self.render)
        glutMouseFunc(self.mouse_button)
        glutMotionFunc(self.mouse_move)
        glutReshapeFunc(self.cam.set_size)
        #self.setup()
        glutMainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = Test()
    test.main()
```

Comment: You might want to remove your email before posting code online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved it, it is the binding issue, in shadow pass fragment shader I simply checked a boolean value to disable reading the texture, but that was not enough. I should have unbind the texture before shadow pass, that is mentioned in documentation as:

Quote from OpenGL Refence:
Special precautions need to be taken to avoid attaching a texture image to the currently bound framebuffer while the texture object is currently bound and potentially sampled by the current vertex or fragment shader.

NVIDIA ignores this, ATI behaves pretty much "undefined" as the documentation says.

Comment: It would be cool if you posted the diff between the broken and working versions.

Answer (score -2):

```
// shadowCoord.z -= 0.0003;
```

Your commented out shadow bias is the solution to your z-fighting problem. Change it to some value e.g. += 0.0005 and you should be good to go.

Comment: depth render result in my framebuffer is similar to the shadow you see, unfortunately it is not z-fighting issue, I commented out that line after many trials.

Comment: stick to proper english, please.

Comment: -1 for poor explanation, arbitrary numbers without explanation and grammar.